# How to determine if the feedback is positive or negative?

Tags: feedback, oscillation, negative-feedback, loop-gain, positive-feedback

[image]

[image]

How to know if I have to apply the formula Af=A/(1-AB) [positive feedback] or Af=A/(1+AB) [negative feedback]?

Comment: Cannot be answerd because the task description does not say anything about pos/neg. feedback. However, one can assume that the feedback factor should be negative. More than that, what is a "feedback of 20 dB"?

Comment: These questions were provided to us by our professor(terrible guy), the answers were provided but we couldn't understand from them, here is the part of the answer concerning "feedback of 20 dB":

N=20dB........>
N=20log(1-AB).........>
20=20log(1-AB).........>
(1 - AB)=10

Comment: When (1-AB)=10, we have AB=-9. Assumption: When A is the forward gain and B the feedback factor, then is AB the loop gain.  When the dominator is >1 (as in this case), we have negative feedback. Terminology according to Bode: (1-AB)="return difference".